# How can I send email to multiple email addresses using Email::Simple in Perl?

Tags: perl, email

I want to be able to send email to multiple email addresses in:

```
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        To      => '"My Name" <myname@something.com>',
        From    => '"Someone1" <some@somewhere.com>',
        Subject => $subject,
    ],
    body => $body
);
sendmail($email, {transport => $transport});
```

Is it possible to write:

```
From => '"Someone1" <some@somewhere.com>', '"Someone2" <some2@somewhere.com>'
```

Comment: Kamal, you've asked 17 questions and haven't accepted any answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put all of the emails inside of an array, then iterate through the array with a foreach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;   
use Email::Send;
use Email::Send::Gmail;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

    my @emails = ('foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com', 'etc@foo.com');
    my $num = @emails;

      foreach (@emails) {
          my $email = Email::Simple->create(
              header => [
                  From    => 'FROM@gmail.com',
                  To      => "$_",
                  Subject => "$subject",
              ],
              body => "$body"
              );

      my $sender = Email::Send->new(
          {   mailer      => 'Gmail',
              mailer_args => [
                  username => 'FROM@gmail.com',
                  password => 'PASSWORD',
                  ]
          }
          );
      eval { $sender->send($email) };

    }
```

**Note:** This will work for whichever module you decide to use.  Here I've used: Email::Send(::Gmail), and Email::Simple::Creator.

Comment: Simpler and less inefficient is to send a single email out. Try `To=>join(", ", @arrayOfEmails),`

Comment: For anyone coming into this the answer below is the better one.

Answer (score 12):

Just use commas in the string:

```
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        To      => join(", ", @people),
        From    => '"Someone1"',
        Subject => $subject,
    ],
    body => $body
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want send mail to multiple mail address the key is `TO` not `FROM`

So, you maybe will be using something like:

```
To => 'mail1@mail.com;mail2@mail.com;mail3@mail.com;mail4@mail.com'
```

Comment: Beware of unintended interpolation of the array `@mail`. Use the single quotes `'`, `q{}` etc. to avoid this mistake!

Comment: syntax error at ./mymail line 24, near "'email@my.com' ;"
syntax error at ./mymail line 27, near "]"
Execution of ./mymail aborted due to compilation errors.
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
   To      => 'email@my.com' ; 'email2@my2.com',

Comment: i found the solution: <code>my $email = Email::Simple->create(
        header => [
            To      => 'k1@dest2.com' ,
            cc      => 'm1@dest2.com' ,
            cc      => 't1@dest.com' ,
            From    => '"Deamon" <bat@sourcehost.com>',
            Subject => $subject,
            ],
        body => $body
        );

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
 </code>